# Linux Top is not reading toprc when connecting via ssh

Tags: ssh, nohup

If I log into my remote host via ssh and run top, it picks up the ~/.toprc configuration file. I can also run the following command successfully

```
 ssh -t <user>@<host> "top -b > top.dat"
```

This keeps the ssh session open forever though. I want to use an ssh session to start a top batch process and exit the ssh session. The issue I'm having is everything I've tried either doesn't work or doesn't pick up the ~/.toprc configuration file.

Here is what I've tried:

```
ssh <user>@<host> "top -b > top.dat &"
ssh -f <user>@<host> "top -b > top.dat"
ssh -f <user>@<host> "nohup top -b > top.dat &"
ssh <user>@<host> "nohup top -b > top.dat &"
ssh -f <user>@<host> "nohup top -b > top.dat"
```

- All with the same results of not picking up ~/.toprc

```
ssh -t <user>@<host> "top -b > top.dat &"
```

- Top exits when the ssh session is closed (immediately)

```
ssh -ft <user>@<host> "top -b > top.dat"
ssh -ft <user>@<host> "nohup top -b > top.dat &"
ssh -ft <user>@<host> "nohup top -b > top.dat"
```

- Does not pick up ~/.toprc and complains that pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Top says it will read $HOME/.toprc. I have verified that $HOME is set in all of these cases and that $HOME/.toprc exists. What is different about these two methods that is causing the asynchronous calls to not pick up the configuration file?

Thanks.

Comment: GENERAL SSH SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Thanks for the suggestion. [superuser link](https://superuser.com/questions/1297379/how-to-ssh-in-start-top-and-close-ssh-session-with-a-custom-toprc)